# Cool robotics projects

Tags: mobile-robot

I'm a robotics student but very new to this field.

Can you suggest any websites which provide projects/helpful info that I can learn from?

Thanks

Comment: For beginner projects, maybe try the "Let's make robots" site.  Lots of things there from simple beginner things to very advanced, with plenty of ideas for mechanical arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into computer vision. Computer vision is frequently used to allow robots to perceive their surroundings.  All you need is a webcam and some time to spend [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html)!  Opencv is an open source computer vision library that is commonly used with robotics. The tutorials will walk you through all the code and explain what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a new field named as soft robotics. This brings new horizons to robotics. Take a look http://softroboticstoolkit.com/